# Looking at your the last card played

Tags: bridge

Is it legal for declarer to look at his/her last card played after the cards from that round are all face down?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, as noted in **Law 66 B** of [The Rules of Duplicate Bridge](http://cdn.acbl.org/documentLibrary/play/Laws-of-Duplicate-Bridge.pdf), with a certain restriction:

> B. Own Last Card
>
> Until a card is led to the next trick, declarer or either
> defender may inspect, but not expose, his own last
> card played.

As the collection of tricks is mechanically different under the [Laws of Rubber Bridge](http://cdn.acbl.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Laws-of-Rubber-Bridge.pdf) **Law 66 - Inspection of Tricks** is similarly a bit different:

> **Law 66 – Inspection of Tricks**
>
> Declarer or either defender may, until a member of
> his side has led or played to the following trick, inspect
> a trick and inquire what card each player has played to
> it. Thereafter, until play ceases, quitted tricks may be inspected
> only to account for a missing or surplus card. ....